# Font Awesome stacked icon hover outline issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, font-awesome

I am using font awesome stacked icon.My code is:

```
<span id="twitterBox" class="fa-stack"><i id="faTwittertSquare" class="fa fa-square fa-  stack-2x colorOrange"></i><i id="fatwitter" class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x colorWhite" title="twitter"></i></span>

<span id="facebookBox" class="fa-stack"><i id="faFacebookSquare" class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x colorOrange"></i><i id="faFacebook" class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x colorWhite" title="facebook"></i></span>
```

jquery code to change color when mouse hover is:

```
$("#twitterBox").hover(function(){
$("#faTwittertSquare").removeClass("colorOrange");
$("#faTwittertSquare").addClass("colorWhite");
$("#fatwitter").removeClass("colorWhite");  
$("#fatwitter").addClass("colorOrange");
},function(){
$("#faTwittertSquare").removeClass("colorWhite");
$("#faTwittertSquare").addClass("colorOrange");
$("#fatwitter").removeClass("colorOrange");
$("#fatwitter").addClass("colorWhite");
});

$("#facebookBox").hover(function(){
$("#faFacebookSquare").removeClass("colorOrange");
$("#faFacebookSquare").addClass("colorWhite");
$("#faFacebook").removeClass("colorWhite");
$("#faFacebook").addClass("colorOrange");
},function(){
$("#faFacebookSquare").removeClass("colorWhite");
$("#faFacebookSquare").addClass("colorOrange");
$("#faFacebook").removeClass("colorOrange");
$("#faFacebook").addClass("colorWhite");
});
```

it's all working but when i mouse hover the icons many time icon right side small line visible.how to fix it.This problem only on chrome browser.

This my image:[image]

my css code:

```
.fa-stack {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
           }

   .fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
       }

    .fa-square-o:before {
        content: "\f096";
                        }

     .fa-square:before {
        content: "\f0c8";
                       }
     .fa-stack-2x {
         font-size: 2em;
                  }

     .fa-stack-2x {
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         text-align: center;
                  }
      .fa-twitter:before {
         content: "\f099";
                         }
       .fa-facebook:before {
         content: "\f09a";
                           }

       .colorWhit{
         color:#FFFFFF;
                 }

       .colorOrange{
          color:#FFA500;
                   }
```

Comment: please post complete CSS of the image you have shown..

Comment: I am not using any extra css styles.only color styles,otherwise all embedded in fontawesome css.

Comment: add class `colorWhite`, `colorOrange`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not just using `:hover`?

Comment: First i am using css :hover but this did not work properly.so i did change to jquery hover method.

Comment: when i mouse hover the square box change to white and twitter bird color change to orange.it's possible css hover style?

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I had :hover on the container element instead of the actual <i class="fa fa-..">, putting :hover on the actual <i> element helped

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/h66t0sde/1/

**CSS:**

```
span.social-box i.social-inner{
    color:#FFA500;
}

span.social-box i.social-outer{
    color:#fff;
}

/* Swap colors on hover */
span.social-box:hover i.social-inner{
    color:#fff;
}

span.social-box:hover i.social-outer{
    color:#FFA500;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="twitterBox" class="fa-stack social-box">
    <i id="faTwittertSquare" class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x social-outer"></i>
    <i id="fatwitter" class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x social-inner" title="twitter"></i>
</span>

<span id="facebookBox" class="fa-stack social-box">
    <i id="faFacebookSquare" class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x social-outer"></i>
    <i id="faFacebook" class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x social-inner" title="facebook"></i>
</span>
```

As a side note, you should avoid classes that include color names, since that locks you into either having confusing names later (if the colors change) or having to track down everywhere you've used it (if you change the name to match the new color).

I also didn't want to rely on the FontAwesome classes for the effect, since those have already changed once. To that end, I came up with some names for the relevant bits that seemed appropriate.

As for the line you're seeing: **no idea.** I don't see that in this jsFiddle when viewing it in Chrome or Firefox, so if you're still seeing it, something in the rest of your CSS is causing that.

Comment: Thank you for helping,it's working but when hover again and again quickly the same issue happened.

Comment: @dev As I mentioned in the last paragraph there: **I'm not seeing that.** No white lines, no dark lines. Something in the rest of your stylesheet is causing that.